# How to allow null value in required nullable DateTime in .NET MVC3 HTML form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, nullable, required

I have tried:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true)]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
public DateTime? BirthDateFrom { get; set; }
```

and

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
[Required]
public DateTime? BirthDateFrom { get; set; }
```

and all combinations with and without `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` and `AllowEmptyStrings`.

In view, I have:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BirthDateFrom)
```

I can submit form with valid date, but with empty string in that field, it just goes red and the form cannot be submitted.
How to allow HTML form submission with null or empty string value in required nullable DateTime?

Comment: It sounds like a contradictio in terminis. If the field is Required why is it nullable? Are you looking for a way to express DateTime.Empty? The requirement is confusing.

Comment: @rene DateTime.Empty would be nice.

Comment: A "required nullable" field makes no sense, which is probably why you can't fit it into how MVC works. That said, removing the required attribute should do the trick, no?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me that simply removing the `[Required]` annotation entirely would meet your requirement.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that the type is nullable implies that the value is **not** required. There is no point in enforcing either a non-null value *or* a null value since the null value doesn't provide any information anyway.

It sounds like the problem you are having is multiple *meanings* of 'null', e.g. 'none' vs 'any' vs 'unknown'. Unfortunately the .NET concept of null doesn't include different *types* of null. The only way to communicate this would be to use either:-

a) 'sentinal' values, e.g. `DateTime.MinValue` communicates something special, and you are sure that `DateTime.MinValue` will never be a valid value in your domain model.

b) use external flags to indicate the meaning of the missing `DateTime` value, e.g. `bool isAny`, `bool isUnknown`, etc. or perhaps an appropriate enum

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with EF, you could make it optional this way.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeObject>().Property(m => m.somefield).IsOptional();            
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```